# locations within radius X around location Y per mysql within the SilverStripe ORM

Tags: mysql, orm, geolocation, silverstripe

I'm filtering locations within radius X around location Y per mysql within SilverStripe 3.4.0.

So far I've implemented a raw-query to get the IDs in the circle and than use those to filter per SilverStripe ORM since I have to filter against multiple criteria and the geofilter is just one of those.

See also Googles "Store Locator" example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

```
$searchDistance = '...';
$searchLat = '...';
$searchLng = '...';

$geolimitedIDs = DB::query('SELECT id, (6371 * acos(cos(radians('.$searchLat.')) * cos(radians(Latitude)) * cos( radians(Longitude) - radians('.$searchLng.')) + sin(radians('.$searchLat.')) * sin(radians(Latitude))))
    AS distance
    FROM "DataObject"
    HAVING distance < ' . $searchDistance . '
    ORDER BY distance')->column();

if($geolimitedIDs) {
    $DataObjects = $DataObjects->filter(array(
        'ID' => $geolimitedIDs
    ));
}
```

In _config I've made the DataObject-Tabel MyISAM

```
DataObject:
  create_table_options:
    MySQLDatabase:
      'ENGINE=MyISAM'
```

This delivers the desired result but needs an extra-query. **Is it possible to add the geo-filter directly to the query within the ORM?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by adding a filter directly to the ORM?

Comment: @Shadow - SilverStripe does lazy-loading. It means we can modify the query $DataObjects. I mean something like $DataObjects->where('...')

Comment: Since your query has a having clause only, I would go with the `having()` method of the dataobject class. However, you can easily include whatever is in the `filter()` method in a where clause of the query. It might be easier to add this criteria to the raw query, rather than trying to find out how to rewrite the raw query in SilverStripe's way.

Comment: @monomummo how about adding your select as an inner join select query and join by the resulting ids?

Comment: @FinBoWa well dono if that would work but AFAIK that way you still have two queries even if it looks like one. Anyway 'll try to make this "having" work as DanHensby & Barry suggested. thx for taking time to comment.

Comment: I didn't say you would remove a query but it would do it the most optimal way: directly on mysql as that's where the data comes from without that extra step on php.

Comment: Just a side note: your query and all the answers below (at this point) calculate the "exact" distance (probably not as exact as it could be but still) for each row. Although this doesn't take much time for a single row when there's 1000s of rows it'll take along time to process the query. It is far quicker to do bounding box search (location is within NE, SE, SW, NW coordinates of the area that fits your distance) and then filter this (much smaller) set in PHP if exact distance is required.

Comment: @koodimyyra - yes that I know. In this case I except a maximum around ~500 rows. My aim is to make the query as "cheep" as possible with a shape of a circle hence I try to make one single query and try to apply the geo-filter as the last of all filters. I dono how fast or slow it 'll be but if it doesn't mach performance expectations I'll go with the bounding-box approach. would you a expect to run into problems with a average-setup (if there is a thing like that). thx for commenting.

Comment: @FinBoWa - yes well true. ATM still struggling with "->having(...)". If I can't make it work the Join certainly 'll be a good alternative. Thx!

Comment: @munomono did you get it working? If yes, how's performance?

Comment: @koodimyyra well it works but ATM still with the extra query. My initial attempt to make having() work failed so far but had not had the time to try harder :) If having() won’t behave FinBoWa's suggestion with a innerJoin sounds good to me. Performance wise I cannot say anything since I haven’t done any stresstests – but I guess it’s oky in the environment I ‘ll use it :)

Comment: @munomono I'd say go for the solution you have now. Having two queries is not that bad, if performing the exact calculations (which is far more expensive than having two queries) isn't going to be a problem either... :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to use the ORM to achieve this. You can pull the `DataQuery` out of the `DataList`, change it (add clauses and so on), then update the `DataList` with it.

Something like:

```
$dataList = MyObject::get();

$dataQuery = $dataList->dataQuery();

$dataQuery->where(...);
$dataQuery->having(...);

$dataList->setDataQuery($dataQuery);
```

Adding and aliasing the select is a bit trickier as you then need to modify the `SQLQuery` against the `DataQuery`, but it should be possible as well, though just adding the haversin formula as the sort will work.

```
$dataList->sort(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "directly to the query within the ORM", but taken to mean "without calling a webservice" then I can offer the below solution...

Note I would recommend using a javascript to do this directly with google maps in a store locator so that the calculation is done synchronously through javascript.

```
function FilterMemberByPostCodeDistance($params, $query){
    $query->where('Member.PostCode IS NOT NULL')
        ->innerJoin('PostCodeToLocation',"SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Member.PostCode,' ', 1),' ',-1) = PostCodeToLocation.OutCode");
 
    $latitude = (float)$postCodeToLocation->Latitude;
    $longitude = (float)$postCodeToLocation->Longitude;
 
    $fTemp = floatval($params['Distance']) / 111.045;
    $fMagicSquareMinLatitude = $latitude - $fTemp;
    $fMagicSquareMaxLatitude = $latitude + $fTemp;
 
    $fTemp = 50.0 / (111.045 * cos(deg2rad($latitude)));
    $fMagicSquareMinLongitude = $longitude - $fTemp;
    $fMagicSquareMaxLongitude = $longitude + $fTemp;
 
    $query->where(
        //Magic Square - this is a simple square to filter out most out of distance values before the magic circle
        //this is done because the circle calculation is much more expensive that the square
 
        'PostCodeToLocation.Latitude  BETWEEN '.$fMagicSquareMinLatitude.' AND '.$fMagicSquareMaxLatitude.'
            AND PostCodeToLocation.Longitude BETWEEN '.$fMagicSquareMinLongitude.' AND '.$fMagicSquareMaxLongitude
 
        //Magic Circle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)
        //This is what does the complicated maths to determine if the postcode is in the cirectle or not
        //not as we are using out codes only, this is a "good estimate" but not 100% accurate
 
        //.' AND acos(sin(RADIANS('.$latitude.'))
        //  * sin(RADIANS(PostCodeToLocation.Latitude))
        //  + cos(RADIANS('.$latitude.'))
        //  * cos(RADIANS(PostCodeToLocation.Latitude))
        //  * cos(RADIANS(PostCodeToLocation.Longitude)
        //  - (RADIANS('.$longitude.'))))
        //  * 6371 <= '.($params['Distance'] * 1.60934) //Kilometers
 
        //REFACTOR of above to process more upfront within PHP
        .' AND acos(sin('.deg2rad($latitude).')
           * sin(RADIANS(PostCodeToLocation.Latitude)) + '.cos(deg2rad($latitude))
        .' * cos(RADIANS(PostCodeToLocation.Latitude))
           * cos(RADIANS(PostCodeToLocation.Longitude) - '.deg2rad($longitude).'))
           * 6371 <= '.($params['Distance'] * 1.60934) //Kilometers
    );
    return $query;
}
```

The function above uses postcodes to lon/lat pairs from teh following publically available data (this bit is UK only).

```
class PostCodeToLocation extends DataObject{

    static $db = array(
        'OutCode'       => 'Varchar(5)',
        'Latitude'      => 'Float',
        'Longitude'     => 'Float'
    );
 
    public static $indexes = array(
        'OutCode'           => true
    );
 
    public function PopulatePostCodeToLocationTable() {
 
        DB::query('TRUNCATE TABLE PostCodeToLocation');
 
        $arrPostCodetoLocations = file(BASE_PATH .'/mysite/.../postcode_outcode_to_latlong.csv');
        if(!empty($arrPostCodetoLocations))
            foreach ($arrPostCodetoLocations as $strPostCodetoLocation) {
                list ($strOutCode,$strLatitude,$strLongitude) = explode(',',$strPostCodetoLocation);
                DB::query("INSERT INTO PostCodeToLocation (OutCode, Latitude, Longitude )
                    VALUES ('".$strOutCode."','".$strLatitude."','".$strLongitude."')"
                );
            }
    }
}
```

The data file for the above is found [here](http://www.silverstrip.es/assets/Uploads/postcode-outcode-to-latlong.csv).

Comment: thx @Barry but to be honest, I like more what I have, than what you suggest. To get the lat/lng for the location-Y I do geocode per Google but to find the locations in the circle I just query the DB per MySQL. But I would like to do that in one single query.

Comment: Well as I said "if you mean..." as I wasn't really sure.  I think what you have is the best situation because you cannot get the HAVING clause into ORM.  Sorry for misinterpreting the question I do that sometimes :)

Comment: And you learn something new everyday... http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SQLQuery.html#_having

Comment: yeah @Barry thats cool, 'll have a go with it and report back. If I'm failing well I'll nag you on IRC :)